# Does python social auth require sticky session?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm encountering fairly frequent exceptions from python social auth of the types:

`AuthMissingParameter & AuthStateMissing`

We're adding a `SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware` class to gracefully handle these but given the frequency I'm curious if our AWS load balancing without sticky sessions is contributing to the frequency of the exceptions?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Mike

Comment: Session stickiness shouldn't affect how python-social-auth works, maybe it affects your framework of choice? What are you using, Django?

Comment: Yes, using Django